# Knockout universal subscribe

Tags: knockout.js

I'd like get notified if any of the 10 observables change on a web page. I can do this by individually subscribing to each (writing the same code 10 times). Is there a way to do it universally, with less code?

pom

Comment: This might help you too: http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/05/creating-smart-dirty-flag-in-knockoutjs.html.  It describes how you can use `ko.toJS` / `ko.toJSON` to grab dependencies for all observables under some root object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here a solution using a computed value:

```
var Model = function () {
    var self = this;
    self.a1 = ko.observable(1);
    self.a2 = ko.observable(1);
    self.a3 = ko.observable(1);
    self.all = ko.computed(function () {
        self.a1();self.a2();self.a3();
    }, this);
    self.all.subscribe(function () {
         console.log("something changed");  
    });
};
ko.applyBindings(new Model());
```

Comment: perfect. thanks! although I needed to add an internal counter there to throttle when app starts, because it would fire a few times before user gets to make changes.

Comment: Perhaps [this](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/throttle-extender.html) can help.